# Creating a non-binary tree by weights of the node and then traversing it

Tags: java, beginner, tree

I wrote this code which adds children to nodes according to the weight of the heading of a non-binary tree. I am a novice programmer, so I would love to know how this code can be improved.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Sample buildTree = new Sample();
        LinkedList<Heading> headings = new LinkedList<>();

        headings.add(new Heading(1, "a"));
        headings.add(new Heading(2, "b"));
        headings.add(new Heading(2, "c"));
        headings.add(new Heading(3, "d"));
        headings.add(new Heading(3, "e"));
        headings.add(new Heading(3, "f"));
        headings.add(new Heading(4, "g"));
        headings.add(new Heading(5, "h"));
        headings.add(new Heading(2, "i"));
        headings.add(new Heading(1, "j"));
        headings.add(new Heading(1, "k"));
        headings.add(new Heading(2, "l"));


        Node structuredHeadings = buildTree.outline(headings);
        System.out.print(buildTree.print(structuredHeadings));
    }

    /* @param  input  A linked list which contains headings with weights and its text
    *  @return A non binary  tree which contains headings sorted by their weights
    *
    */

    Node outline(LinkedList<Heading> input) {

        Node mainNode = new Node(new Heading(0, ""));

        Node currentNode = mainNode;
        Node parentNode = null;

        for (Heading head : input) {

            if (head == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if(head.weight < 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Weight can not be negative");
            }

            if (currentNode.head.weight == head.weight) {
                currentNode = parentNode;
                currentNode.children.add(new Node(head));
                currentNode = currentNode.children.getLast();

            }

            if (currentNode.head.weight < head.weight) {
                parentNode = currentNode;
                currentNode.children.add(new Node(head));
                currentNode = currentNode.children.getLast();

            }



            if (currentNode.head.weight > head.weight) {

                currentNode = mainNode;
                while (true) {
                    int weight = currentNode.children.getLast().head.weight;
                    if (weight == head.weight) {

                        parentNode = currentNode;
                        currentNode.children.add(new Node(head));
                        currentNode = currentNode.children.getLast();
                        break;
                    }
                    currentNode = currentNode.children.getLast();
                }
            }


        }

        return mainNode;

    }



    String print(Node node) {

        String build  = " Node(Heading(" + node.head.weight + ", '" + node.head.text + "')" + ", List( ";
        for (Node child : node.children) {

            build +=   print(child);

        }
        build += ") ";
        return build;

    }



    static class Heading {
        int weight;
        String text;

        Heading(int weight, String text) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.text = text;
        }

    }

    static class Node {
        Heading head;
        LinkedList<Node> children;

        Node(Heading head) {
            this.head = head;
            children = new LinkedList<>();
        }

    }
}
```